# Latest research and explanation on how semi-supervised learning is performing better than supervised?

Tags: references, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

So in AAAI 2020 also semi-supervised learning is given the push. There are some intuitive reasoning provided by people but since the research is so fast, I wanted to know actually what is the latest theoretical, intuitive reasoning which gives more emphasis on semi-supervised learning and what is the modern consensus by researchers on this approach ( meaning that it is just a hype or this approach can actually yeild results ).

Some pointers or resources to it will be appreciated.

Comment: onestly, this is too broad. semi-supervised is a label that has been attached to a very varied set of methods

Comment: But I am not asking for a all the methods it has, I am asking why everybody is just supporting it?

Comment: because it makes sense, and it works sometimes, it always has. maybe provide some links to provide context for those endorsements you are talking about